# Наречие или краткая форма

Tags: прилагательные, наречия

Вопрос для самых педантичных:
"Это хорошо. Это плохо."
*Хорошо* и *плохо* здесь неречия, да?

"Какая из машин тебе нравится? - Эта хороша."
Здесь *хороша* - краткая форма прилагательного.

Как можно с уверенностью сказать, что в первом случае мы имеем дело именно с наречием, а не с краткой формой прилагательного?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Некоторые наречия легко перепутать с прилагательными в краткой форме. Например,

> Лето было зелено и свежо и Летом было зелено и свежо.

В таком случае важно правильно поставить вопрос, ведь в первом предложении «зелено и свежо» связываются с подлежащим вопросом «каково?», а во втором «как?». «Каково», так же как и какой, какая, какое – это вопрос прилагательного.

Мне кажется, что Вы искали вот это:

Некоторые наречия могут выступать как именная часть сказуемых. Чаще всего это сказуемые безличных предложений (На море тихо), однако некоторые наречия могут служить и сказуемыми двусоставных предложений (Разговор будет начистоту. Она замужем).
Наречия, выступающие как сказуемые безличных предложений, иногда выделяют в самостоятельную часть речи или в самостоятельный разряд внутри наречия и называются словами **категории состояния** (словами состояния, **предикативными наречиями**).

Категория состояния
Слова категории состояния обозначают

> состояние природы (Было холодно), человека (У меня на душе радостно. Мне жарко), оценку действий (Можно пойти в кино).

Слова категории состояния с суффиксом -о, образованные от прилагательных, могут иметь степени сравнения

> (С каждым днем становилось все холоднее / более холодно).

В лингвистике, действительно, иногда выделяют эти слова в самостоятельную часть речи, называемую словами категории состояния (предикативными наречиями, безлично-предикативными словами). Слова этой группы делятся на слова, которые могут употребляться и в других синтаксических позициях

> (ср.: Море тихо (прил.) — Он сидел тихо (нар.) — В классе тихо (кат. сост.)),

и слова, которые могут употребляться только в функции сказуемых безличных предложений: *можно, нельзя, боязно, совестно, стыдно, пора, жаль* и др. Отличительной особенностью этих слов является то, что они не сочетаются с подлежащим и теряют способность обозначать признак действия (весело) или предмет (лень). Однако в лингвистике также широко распространена точка зрения, согласно которой слова категории состояния считаются подгруппой **наречий**.

Кстати, если Вы хотите сказать, что *это* может быть указательным местоимением, то ситуация должна быть более определенной, объясняющей предмет или явление,определяемое указательным местоимением.

Comment: Спасибо за анализ, и за относительную конечность ответа. У меня сложилось впечатление, что эта самая катигория состояния была придумана, чтобы ответить на этот странный вопрос. Можно попросить вас добавить ссылку на источник?

Comment: videotutor-rusyaz.ru›Ученикам›Наречие

Comment: http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/57-narechie.html
кликабельная ссылка :)

Answer (score 1):

> Пошёл дождь. Это (*как?*) хорошо.

This is an adverb.

> Передо мною три ведра. Это (*каково?*) — хорошо, это — так себе, а это — плохо.

Those (including *так себе*) are predicative adjectives.

Comment: Простите, я не могу найти ничего внятного про предикативные прилагательные в русском языке, только про предикативные наречия. Если же здесь мы имеем дело с предикативными наречиями, а не прилагательными, то ваш ответ не помогает.

Comment: @PashaSyrnikov: it's same as in English. *Красивая машина* is not a sentence, the adjective is attributive. *Машина красива* is a sentence, the adjective is predicative. In modern Russian, short forms of adjectives can only be used as predicates (but not vice versa).

Comment: @PashaSyrnikov: but actually my point was that adjectives and adverbs answer different questions.

Comment: I see your point! However, you could sort of ask "каково?" in the first sentence as well. Generally, I find explanations based on questions useful only for native speakers, and even for them they don't always give definitive answers. I'll keep looking, but thank you for your effort.

Comment: @PashaSyrnikov: to put it other way, adjectives define or modify nouns (and nominals which can act as nouns), while adverbs modify other parts of speech (verbs, adjectives, other adverbs etc., even phrases and sentences). The words in *насекомое безумно красиво* are a noun, an adverb (modifying the adjective) and an adjective (defining the noun); those in *насекомое безумно* are a noun and an adjective (defining the noun).

Answer (score 0):

Если описание относится к глаголу ("это *есть* хорошо"), оно выражается наречием; если к существительному ("*машина* хороша") - прилагательным.

Comment: если это - частица, то я с вами согласен.
но если это - указательное местоимение, то можно спорить, что хорошо относится к этому местоимению, а не к глаголу.

Answer (score 0):

*В первом примере* для классификации важен смысл, стоящий за местоимением. Например, в некотором контексте (сопоставление двух стихотворений, на которые ссылаются при помощи местоимения) можно говорить о кратких прилагательных (смысл: одно стихотворение хорошо, другое - плохо). В более типичном для этого же примера случае выявляемая часть речи относится к тому, чему нельзя приписать свойство, выражаемое прилагательным, поскольку местоимение "это" замещает не отдельно взятое существительное (как в примере со стихотворениями), а ситуацию, для описания которой требуется законченное выражение, например, сказанному "это хорошо" предшествует: "долгожданное письмо пришло". Соответственно, такому выражению нельзя непосредственно приписать прилагательного "хороший" (зелёный и пр.), но соотв. ситуации можно дать оценку в целом при помощи наречия (каково это?): "то, что письмо пришло" (= это), "хорошо".

*Во втором примере* проще: кр. прилагательное привязано к "машине" (отдельное существительное) и характеризует её свойства.

Comment: в вашем ответе всё логично, но у меня есть пару вопросов. 1. Почему "такому выражению нельзя непосредственно приписать прилагательного"? 2. В своем ответе @Quassnoi пишет, что на вопрос "каково?" отвечают предикативные прилагательные, а не наречия. Кому из вас мне верить? :)

Comment: "Каково (тебе от произошедшего)" и "каково (то стихотворение, о котором мы говорили)" - два разных вопроса к разным частям речи.

Comment: Что касается ответа на первый вопрос, Quassnoi только что в комментарии, аналогично мною сказанному, противопоставил существительное законченному выражению - по связи с прилагательным и наречием соответственно.