# What are the uses of words ending in но

Tags: грамматика, падежи

I see words ending in -но with the stem coming from adjectives and verb.
Example are;
можно
нужно
понятно

Comment: You can find some information here, but the question is too broad.https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/13291/what-part-of-speech-is-нельзя/13296#13296

Comment: Or search for predicatives .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s like asking at English SE what words usually end by “-ly”. It’s too broad and hardly helps anyone learning Russian.

Answer (score 1):

In сommon they are adverbs.

- Можно мне съесть это яблоко ?
- Можно. Можно тебе съесть это яблоко.
- Но нужно ли тебе есть его ?
- Да нужно, нужно, я вас уверяю.
- Понятно ли тебе это ?
- Да, мне всё понятно.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for English equivalent, Russian "-но" words may be compared to English words with "-able" ("-ible") and "-ful" suffixes.

For example:

- permit permissible можно
- understand understandable понятно (понятный)
- need needful нужно (нужный)

This is not a rule, because many words in this matrix do not exist in both languages - but this would hopefully help you to understand.