# What is the case of the shortened adjective "понятно" in "Стало понятно, что ..."?

Tags: падежи, наречия, impersonal

> Стало **понятно**, что ...

It seems that when the verb "стать" is used in the sense of "become ...",  the instrumental case follows. According to [Wiki](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9), however,  the instrumental case of the adjective "понятный" is listed as "поня́тным", and "понятно" seems to be its shortened form, whatever its case is.

So I wonder if this shortened form "понятно" applies to all cases of the adjective "понятный"?

And is it more common to use "понятно" than "поня́тным"  in conversation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a shortened adjective here, this is an adverb.

Usually adverbs like this are conveyed using adjectives or "to feel + adv." in English (*ему одиноко* "he's feeling lonely", *ему холодно* "he's cold") etc., however English does not have a passive version of "to understand", so it might not indeed be obvious that *понятно* here is an adverb.

Adverbs with close meanings, like *стало ясно* "it became clear", *стало очевидно* "it became obvious" etc. might make this pattern more clear.

So *понятно* here is an adverb, and as an adverb it does not decline or agree in number and gender.

There are similar constructs, where *понятно* is a true adjective: *математика стала ему понятной (понятна)*. Here, the full form adjective is in instrumental and the short form one is in nominative, and they both agree in gender with the noun they define.

Comment: "To be understood" is the English passive voice of 'to understand'.

Comment: @YellowSky: do either of "I'm understood" or "It's understood to me" mean *мне понятно*?

Comment: Both. The sentencence structure of your two languages is different. What's the problem?

Comment: Hi. Is "приятно" in "Очень приятно" an adverb? Or the shortened adjective?

Comment: It's neither an adverb nor a shortened adjective.

Answer (score 2):

"Понятно" is translated as *understandabe*, so *стало понятно* is simply '[It] became understandable'.

Answer (score 0):

**Понятно** is either a shortened form of adjective or an adverb (there is support for both theories), but neither adverbs nor shortened adjectives have cases.

**Стало понятным** is rarely used in everyday speech, but it is a valid expression and you may find it in written texts.

Answer (score 0):

The word "понятно" in your example is called "категория состояния"(category of state).It's a certain word class, which has similar semantic, syntactic and morphological qualities. The main of them are : 1. In the sentence it functions as an impersonal predicate. 2. The meaning isn't an action, but a state. 3.It doesn't change (no gender, no case,etc.) 4. And in the form it looks like a noun, an adjective or an adverb.

> **Грустно и тяжело** было видеть ее в столь нелегком положении.

The verbs "делаться, становиться, стать, быть" show us that this is "категория состояния"

> Когда я ее слушал, мне становилось грустно; Мне сделалось неловко.

Such words don't modify (don't belong to) any other word class.

> 1.Она глядела **грустно** (an adverb –здесь наречие определяет глагол). 2. Лицо девушки было **грустно**  (a short adjective, can also be "грустным"-- в данном случае краткое прилагательное определяет существительное)  3.Девушке было **грустно** (category of state категория состояния)

You can read more here:
[Наречие или краткая форма](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/12826/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0)

[What part of speech is "нельзя"?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/13291/what-part-of-speech-is-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%8f/13296?s=2|17.6329#13296)