# Word class of “хорошо” in “Как хорошо”

Tags: грамматика, наречия, impersonal

According to my Russian learning book, short adjectives are formed by taking the root of the adjective and adding:

- -ø for male (null ending)
- -a for female
- -o for neutral

Thus, the adjective *красивый, -ая, -ое* will give the following three short adjectives: *красив, красива, красиво*.

My book also mentions that short adjectives are often used after *так* and *как*.

---

**My question is:** in the expression *Как хорошо!*, what is the word class of the word *хорошо*, and why? I’ve heard many times that it is an adverb in this case, but what I see in my learning book would lead me to say that it’s a short adjective (also because one can say *Какой хороший*, which is then the long form).

Comment: You are asking the same question with different words. Do you read the answers?

Comment: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/15549/what-is-the-case-of-the-shortened-adjective-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-in-%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be

Comment: @V.V. I read all answers (to my questions at least). I don’t understand which other question are you referring to?

Comment: Ah thank you for pointing me to that other question. I tried to search for similar questions to mine but didn’t find anything (I couldn’t guess that it had been answered with another word). Mark it as a duplicate if you wish!

Comment: it's OK, the more imformation, the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Как хорошо!`** is an impersonal (subjectless) sentence and the role of `хорошо` is indeed adverbial, it answers the question `how?` and not `which?`. But predicates in these sentences do assume neuter gender.

Other examples

> На улице `темно` - **It**'s dark outside
>   Было `интересно` - **It** was interesting
>   Вчера `похолодало` - **It** got colder yesterday
>   Проводить время одному `скучно` - **It**'s boring to spend time alone
>   Крышу `сорвало` ветром - The roof got torn off with the wind
>   Ему `стало` легче - He got/felt better

Answer (score 2):

Depending on context "*хорошо*" may be an adverb and a short adjective.

It's an adverb describing conditions or states:

> как хорошо!
>
> мне хорошо - I feel good
>
> на улице стало хорошо - it (the weather) became good/nice outside.

It's a short adjective when describing objects and other things:

> Вино хорошо - wine is good
>
> Представление было хорошо - the presentation/performacne was good

*Honestly speaking, "хороший" is used not very often in its short form so both examples don't sound really natural.*